# Moment not formatting this date May 04, 2016

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The server is giving me a date format like this `May 04, 2016`

```
var month = moment('May 04, 2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('M')
```

`month` Gives me `4`, obviously May should be `5`, it's giving me the day it seems, and not the month.

How do I format the date the server gives me to determine the month using moment.js?

EDIT:

Not really sure why I am downvoted I actually tried the answer below and still get

[image]

Comment: *"I actually tried the answer below and still get"* You've used `MM`. The answer below (if you're referring to mine) says `MMM`. [It matters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Silly on my behalf I mean, but you're right. Thanks guys, needed the extra minds!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you give `moment` two string arguments, [the documentation says](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) the second is meant to be the format of the first. `MM-DD-YYYY` is not the format of `May 04, 2016`. The format of `May 04, 2016` would be `MMM DD, YYYY`:

```js
console.log(moment("May 04, 2016", "MMM DD, YYYY").format("M"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

var month = moment('May 04, 2016', 'MMM-DD-YYYY').format('MM')

Change "MM" to "MMM" and .format('M') to format('MM').

Comment: If the OP wants `"5"` as a result, `.format("MM")` is incorrect.

Comment: In this link say that month will return 0-11. And .format('M') is correct Im sorry. [link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/)

Comment: To correct your answer (the `MM` vs. `M` thing), you can use the "edit" link. However, `MMM-DD-YYYY` is not the right format for parsing `May 04, 2016`. Suggest just deleting.

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation, the months ranges from 0 to 11.

So for May, it would return 4.

Reference : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/

Comment: I used format, same as OP but documentation clearly states that the month are indexed from 0 to 11. So january : 0, feb : 1 .. May : 4

https://jsfiddle.net/ww96dtwL/1/

Comment: The documentation clearly says that `month` will return 0-11. But [`format` quite clearly is documented](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to return `1-12`: *"Month - M - 1 2 ... 11 12"* (Because it's formatting for output, and only programmers write dates with the month 0-based, not most people.)